# Obtaining value based in two rows in pandas as new row

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe with genes:

```
    pName     genotype  feture
    person_1    TT    feature_1 
    person_1    TY    feature_2 
    person_1    YY    feature_3
    person_1    TY    feature_4 
    person_2    TT    feature_1 
    person_2    TT    feature_2 
    person_2    YY    feature_3 
    person_2    YY    feature_4
```

And I have collection of some ills. Most of them based on one genotype for example:

```
IF feature 1 == YY interpretation =  RED
IF feature 1 == TY interpretation =  BLUE
IF feature 1 == TT interpretation =  Green
```

I wrote pandas code for that:

```
data.loc[(data['feture'] == 'feature_1') & (data['genotype'] == 'YY'),'interpretation'] = "RED"
data.loc[(data['feture'] == 'feature_1') & (data['genotype'] == 'TY'),'interpretation'] = "BLUE"
data.loc[(data['feture'] == 'feature_1') & (data['genotype'] == 'TT'),'interpretation'] = "Green"
etc. (3x 10 feauters)
```

So I got:

```
     pName     genotype  feture  interpetation
    person_1    TT    feature_1  Green
    person_1    TY    feature_2  ...
    person_1    YY    feature_3  
    person_1    TY    feature_4 
    person_2    TT    feature_1  Green
    person_2    TT    feature_2  ...
    person_2    YY    feature_3 
    person_2    YY    feature_4
```

but I have problem for based on two genes features. 
For example:

```
IF feature_3 == YY interpretation =  RED
IF feature_4 == TT interpretation =  BLUE
```

but additionally:

```
(IF feature_3 == YY) & (IF feature_4 == TT) interpretation =  R/B
```

And as U can see I need to add new row for each person who has feature3 and feature4.

Final dataFrame will be looks that:

```
     pName     genotype  feture  interpetation
    person_1    TT    feature_1  Green
    person_1    TY    feature_2  ...
    person_1    YY    feature_3  RED
    person_1    TY    feature_4  BLUE
    person_1    YYTY  new_feature_34     R/W    #new feature based on two others
    person_2    TT    feature_1  Green
    person_2    TT    feature_2  ...
    person_2    YY    feature_3  BLUE
    person_2    YY    feature_4  BLUE
    person_2    YYYY  new_feature_34     W/W    #new feature based on two others
```

SO IF:

```
(IF feature_3 == YY) & (IF feature_4 == TY)
```

I added new row with:
person, both genotypes and combine names and interpretation. As in example.

And I have no idea how can I do it by pandas. I tried to found a solution but I didn't.

I solve my problem by pure python:

1) creating list of persons.

2) For Iterate on df and check two features for each person.

3) add new feature to dataframe: person + CAT(genotype1, genotype2) + newFeatureXY + interpretation

But it sooo slow if I have more than 1000 person. 
It's possible to do that in pandas?

Comment: There's either a feature_3/4 at a given row of your initial dataframe. Then why check two condtions `(IF feature_3 == YY) & (IF feature_4 == TT) interpretation =  R/B`?

Comment: Are you saying you're adding them later?

Comment: yes, they added later based on two another features

Comment: I cannot really understand. You say that you want `feature_4 == TT`, but no line in the sample dataframe has both feature_4 and TT. Additionaly what is `CAT(genotype1, genotype2)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `groupby` and `apply` here to build the new lines, and then append them to the dataframe. But as the function building the new lines is not trivial, I would declare it explicitely:

```
def feat34(x):
    y = (x['feture'] == 'feature_3') & (x['genotype'] == 'YY')
    z = (x['feture'] == 'feature_4') & (x['genotype'] == 'TY')
    if y.any() and z.any():
        return pd.DataFrame([['YYTY','new_feature_34', 'R/B']],
                            columns=x.columns[1:])
    else:
        return None

data = data.append(data.groupby('pName').apply(feat34).reset_index(
    level=0)).sort_values('pName')
```

with the sample data, it gives:

```
      pName genotype          feture interpretation
0  person_1       TT       feature_1          Green
1  person_1       TY       feature_2            NaN
2  person_1       YY       feature_3            NaN
3  person_1       TY       feature_4            NaN
0  person_1     YYTY  new_feature_34            R/B
4  person_2       TT       feature_1          Green
5  person_2       TT       feature_2            NaN
6  person_2       YY       feature_3            NaN
7  person_2       YY       feature_4            NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate new column `'feature_genotype'` and use `groupby` and `apply` as Serge Ballesta suggested:

```
import pandas as pd

n = 20_000
name = ['person_']*4*n
name = [p + str(i//4) for i, p in enumerate(name)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'pName': name,
                  'genotype': ['TT', 'TY', 'YY', 'TY']*n,
                  'feature': ['feature_1', 'feature_2', 'feature_3', 'feature_4']*n,
                  'interpretation': ['Green', '...', 'RED', 'BLUE']*n})


def fill_values(x, new):
    v = x.feature_genotype.values
    if 'feature_3_YY' in v and 'feature_4_TY' in v:
        new.append({'pName': x.name,
                            'genotype': 'YYTY',
                            'feature': 'new_feature_34',
                            'interpretation': 'R/W'})

df['feature_genotype'] = df.feature + '_' + df.genotype
new = []    
%time df.groupby('pName').apply(lambda x: fill_values(x, new))

Wall time: 1.19 s
```

So, for 80000 dataset it takes 1.19 sec. It's also important for drop duplicates, because `apply` sometimes process the first group twice:

```
new = pd.DataFrame(new)
new = new.drop_duplicates()
df = df.append(new).drop('feature_genotype', axis=1).sort_values('pName')
```

But actually, I suggest it would be more comfortable to process this df with one row per each unique `'pName'` creating columns for each unique value of the other columns.